# Can I use two different variables in a grafana query?

Tags: grafana, promql

I have two variables: one is called hostname and the other hostname_regex (hostname is of type query and hostname_regex is of type constant).
I want to run a query where the results displayed are of both what is picked in the hostname variable and what is picked in the hostname_regex variable.

I tried using the following query:

```
topk(15, sort_desc(mem_used_percent{site=~"$site",env=~"$env",team=~"$team",service=~"$service",hostname=~"$hostname|^$hostname_regex.*"}))
```

But I am only shown the values picked in the "hostname" variables.

Comment: It should work. Maybe your variable contains some symbols with special meaning in regex, like `()`?